# jquery ui accordion scrollbar

Tags: jquery-ui, scrollbar, accordion

I have a jqueryUI accordion which looks great.  I will have around 10 section (headers) which will just fit on the screen.  However, on a smaller screen it will cut off some of my section headers.  (I can already simulate this by shrinking the browser window). How can I have a scrollbar appear if the accordion headers don't fit vertically?

The accordion is wrapped in a div with no options set.  It's as if a need a MIN height for the div to ensure all the headers can appear, with some room for the section content.

My full code is as follows:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#settingsnavigation" ).accordion({ 
      heightStyle: "fill",
      clearStyle: true, 
      autoHeight: false }
    );
  });
  </script>

<div id="settingsnavigation" style="width:220px">
  <h3>General</h3>
  <div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">User</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Security</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Units &amp; Ranges</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Notifications</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Vehicles</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Device</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Financial</h3>
  <div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Balance</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">History</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Purchase</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Vehicle: Cadillac Seville STS</h3>
  <div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">General</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Units &amp; Ranges</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Select Reminders</div>
      <div class="settingsubsection">Edit Reminders</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide code and/or jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

CSS for the container div should be

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Nope when I shrink the browser the lower headings/sections of the accordion just get cut off with no scroll bar.